# Github says I have a Node security vulnerability in package-lock (cryptiles) but it's not installed in package.json and I'm not using it, solutions?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Basically, I have a node project and recently github has flagged a potential security vulnerability in one of my dependencies.

It's with cryptiles being version 3.1.2 and recommends I go to version 4.1.2.

Cryptiles is in my `package-lock.json` but I don't currently have it installed in my `package.json` nor is it being used anywhere in my project.

I've never worked just with package-lock.json, I tried to change the version in there, but when I run npm install, it changes it back. Solutions?

Would upgrading Node solve it? One of my npm modules? Should I just dismiss this since it's not being used in my project? Want to make sure i'm being safe though.

Here is the two sections in my `package-lock.json` with `cryptiles`, neither that nor `hawk` are installed in my `package.json`

```js
    },
    "cryptiles": {
      "version": "3.1.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles/-/cryptiles-3.1.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-qJ+7Ig9c4l7FboxKqKT9e1sNKf4=",
      "requires": {
        "boom": "5.2.0"
      },
```

And here:

```js
},
    "hawk": {
      "version": "6.0.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk/-/hawk-6.0.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-miowhl2+U7Qle4vdLqDdPt9m09K6yZhkLDTWGoUiUzrQCn+mHHSmfJgAyGaLRZbPmTqfFFjRV1QWCW0VWUJBbQ==",
      "requires": {
        "boom": "4.3.1",
        "cryptiles": "3.1.2",
        "hoek": "4.2.1",
        "sntp": "2.1.0"
      },
```

Would appreciate any help and anyone who can help me understand the situation so this doesn't happen again.

Comment: Adding newline to group your text into logical parts, and using highlight greatly improves the reasbility of a question, meakes it easier to read and more likely to be answeres. So if you want someone to invest time to answer, then invest time to make the question easier to read.

Comment: See how hawk **requires** cryptiles? Something else will require hawk. Follow the chain back to the package you have chosen to use.

Comment: It doesn't say that it's a *direct* dependency, it just says that it's somewhere in your dependencies. Some module is using `hawk`, and you are using that module.

Comment: You can try to run npm audit --fix. But this not always works and could update some package, so you will need retest your app.

Comment: Thanks to Quentin and Bergi, I followed the chain all the way up to bcrypt, I updated the version and it removed the dependency, issue fixe

Comment: Do not add the solution to your question. If you solved the problem then create an answer for it and accept that answer.

Answer (score 2):

npm ls {module name} will allow you to see the dependency tree. Updating the parent dependency usually fixes the transitive dependency (dependency of dependency).
This article can be helpful if you need to force a dependency version.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions

Answer (score 0):

Found moderate severity vulnerabilities

run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Answer (score -1):

Following some suggestions above, I followed the depedencies to see which npm module I installed used it. I upgraded the module and it removed the dependency and issue

Comment: Can you tell me which module you found it in?  I'm having the same issue, but can't find the dependency.

Comment: In my case, the vulnerability was due to an old version of request (which used an old version of cryptiles as a dependency)